# Getting array of filenames in a directory which contains substring in their name

Tags: php, directory, filenames

I have a directory that has some file names. I want to get all the files in that directory which contains substring.

```
MyDir =>
    - Hello12.pdf
    - ABC.pdf
    - hello.pdf
    - JohnDoe.pdf
    - hello33.pdf
```

I want to give `'Hello'` and get all the filenames containing Hello with their extension; and get result like `['Hello12.pdf', 'hello.pdf, 'hello33.pdf']`

```
$dir = public_path('files/MyDir');
```

How can I get the files in an array containing 'Hello' substring in their filename in MyDir directory?

---

Is going from this way a good approach?

```
foreach(glob($dir . '/*.pdf') as $filename){
     var_dump($filename);
}
```

Comment: best to use `glob()`

Comment: I added an update in the question. That way?

Comment: `foreach (glob("*[Hh][Ee][Ll][Ll][Oo]*") as $filename) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scandir` method to get all file names. then iterate through it and find matches

```
$dir = public_path('files/MyDir');
$files =  scandir ($dir);
$match = "Hello";
$match_files = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if((stripos($file, $match) !== false)
    $match_files[]=$file;
}
print_r($match_files);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like charm. Just out of curiosity, is `glob()` or `scandir()` better?

Answer (score 1):

first you need to scan dir and then find the string and add them to array

```
<?php
$i = scandir(__DIR__ . '/files/MyDir', 1);
$array = [];
foreach ($i as $x) {
    if (strpos($x, 'hello') !== FALSE) {
        $array[] = $x;
    }
}
echo var_export($array, true);
```